# sfCaptchaGDPlugin Validation

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, captcha

I'm trying to implement the sfCaptchaGDPlugin for Symfony 1.4.

I've created a `CommentForm` Class which extends the `BaseForm`.

```
class CommentForm extends BaseForm
{
    public function configure()
      {
        $stars = array('star1', 'star2', 'star3', 'star4', 'star5');
        $fields = array();
        $fields['Subject'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default' => 'Bewertung'));
        $fields['Voting'] = new btRatingStars(array('choices' => $stars), array('class' => 'star'));
        $fields['Username'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
        $fields['Captcha'] = new sfWidgetCaptchaGD();
        $fields['Text'] = new sfWidgetFormTextarea();
        $fields['ObjectId'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
        $fields['Userid'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
        $fields['Type'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
        $this->setWidgets($fields);
      }

    }
```

I can see the Captcha and enter a the Code. Now i'm trying to submit the Form via a AJAX request.

```
 $('.btnsmall').click(function() {
    $.post('<?php echo url_for('forum/saveComment') ?>', {
      data: $('.form').serializeArray()
    }, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }); 
    return false;
  });
```

the following action is looks like this:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
      $data = $request->getParameter('data');
      $formdata = array();
      foreach ($data as $field)
      {
        $formdata[$field['name']] = $field['value'];
      }  
      $form = new CommentForm();    
      $form->setDefaults($formdata);  
      $form->setValidator('Captcha', new sfCaptchaGDValidator());
      $form->bind(array(
          'Captcha' => $formdata['Captcha'],
      ));
      var_dump($form->hasErrors());
      var_dump($form->valid());
    }
```

the result is the Following:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCaptchaGDPlugin/1_4_6?tab=plugin_readme)

The Problem was the Cross Site Protection...
Had to implement the csrf token via 
$form['_csrf_token'];

Comment: Could you show us the `CommentForm` class?

Comment: have you overwritten the default validator for 'captcha'?

Comment: no, i didnt. but i'm also wondering why the form says that it has errors. i mean, i have no validators :-U

i have deactivated all fields except the name and the subject... it also says its not valid... :-(

Comment: problem solved. the problem was the csrf token. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I rendered each `Formfield` separate by `echo $form['fieldname']`. I forgot the `csrf` Token. After I added `echo $form['_csrf_token']` the Form passed the Validators inclusive the Captcha.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it